# Java: gRPC with FutureStub and ListenableFuture

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I'm learning **gRPC** with **Java** and as an example I've defined three `request` types (*cuboid*, *sphere* and *cylinder*) and a single response type (String) where I put message about the calculated volume of a specific geometry. I followed [this](https://www.baeldung.com/grpc-introduction) example, which use blocking stub on the client side and the program runs correctly. However, I want to try the asynchronous approach, so here is my client side code, written with `newFutureStub` and `ListenableFuture`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder
                .forAddress("localhost",8080)
                .usePlaintext()
                .build();

        GeometryServiceGrpc.GeometryServiceFutureStub stub = GeometryServiceGrpc.newFutureStub(channel);

         ListenableFuture<Response> cuboidResp = stub.calcCuboidVol(CuboidVolumeRequest.newBuilder()
                .setLength(2)
                .setWidth(3)
                .setHeight(4)
                .build());
         cuboidResp.addListener(() -> {
             try {
                 System.out.println(cuboidResp.get().getResponse());
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }, command -> {
             command.run();
         });

        ListenableFuture<Response> sphereResp = stub.calcSphereVol(SphereVolumeRequest.newBuilder()
                .setRadius(2)
                .build());
        sphereResp.addListener(() -> {
            try {
                System.out.println(sphereResp.get().getResponse());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, command -> {
            command.run();
        });

        ListenableFuture<Response> cylinderResp = stub.calcCylinderVol(CylinderVolumeRequest.newBuilder()
                .setRadius(2)
                .setHeight(3)
                .build());
        cylinderResp.addListener(() -> {
            try {
                System.out.println(cylinderResp.get().getResponse());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, command -> {
            command.run();
        });

        channel.shutdown();
}
```

Since we must use `ListenableFuture` I attach its method `addListener()` to each return instance of a specific geometry method (the `Response` message has a single `string` field called `response`). Basically, the desired result is just to print the calculations once they're ready and that's why a `System.out.println` is called in the `runnable` part. Although the program gets executed successfully, nothing is printed. But if check a specific geometry, then all results appear to the console. Example:

```
        if(!cylinderResp.isDone()) {
           try {
                cylinderResp.get().getResponse();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Does this means that the program terminates before the asynchronous part is completed? And is the executable part (`commnad`) written correctly (I searched and found out that this part can be executed by a `ExecutorService` if we want the code to be run on different thread(s) - not a requirement in my case)?

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't use `addListener` directly, but use e.g. `Futures.transform` or the like to add follow-up Futures that you can then wait for completion.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. It's very interesting why after only waiting for a single ```ListenableFuture``` (the second code snippet) all of the three ```runnable``` parts get executed.

Answer (score 0):

`Does this means that the program terminates before the asynchronous part is completed?` Yes, that's right, you should wait it execute complete by call `cylinderResp.get()` or `channel.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

`And is the executable part (commnad) written correctly`, If you want run task in specify thread pool you should add a `ExecutorService`, or it will executed by default thread pool.

For completely asynchronous you should use `StreamObserver`.

For more detail of how to use gRPC in Java you can reference my code [helloworlde/grpc-java-sample](https://github.com/helloworlde/grpc-java-sample)